# How to use/import data in App.vue from constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm initializing my app with `main.js` like so,

```
import App from './App.vue';

const store = {
    items: [{
        todo: 'Clean Apartment.',
    },{
        todo: 'Mow the lawn!',
    },{
        todo: 'Pick up eggs, milk & flour',
    }, {
        todo: 'Watch the big game',
    }],
};

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app-zone',
    data: store, // is this not sending the store data into App.vue?
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

I'm trying to make use of `items` within `App.vue`. But I'm not sure how or if it's passed down into it.

App.vue looks like so...

```
export default {
    props['items'], // not sure if that's correct
    created() {
        console.log(this.items);  // always returns undefined
    }
}
```

So how do I get data from the constructor and make use of it? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass `props` via the `render` function, you need to provide a `context` object. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

```
render: h => h(App, {
  props: {
    items: store.items
  }
})
```